# How to start a ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC2 app that doesn't listen to the localhost

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

how can I start the [ASP.NET Core with the dotnet CLI samples](https://github.com/aspnet/cli-samples) so that they don't listen to the localhost?

This command doesn't work:

```
dotnet run --server.urls=http://*:5000
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're trying to do requires you to add command-line args to your configuration in the `Main` method of your application.  Add something like this before you create your `WebHostBuilder` object:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .Build();
```

And then add this to the `WebHostBuilder` object before calling `.Build()` on it:

`.UseConfiguration(config)`

You'll also need to add a dependency to project.json:

`"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0-rc2-final",`

And finally, add a using statement to the file that your `Main` method is in:

`using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;`

Example `Main` method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddCommandLine(args)
        .Build();

    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseConfiguration(config)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
    host.Run();
}
```

Comment: You can also configure urls directly in code, like in [this samle](https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/blob/dev/samples/SampleApp/Startup.cs): `.UseKestrel().UseUrls("http://*:5000")`