# dotnet run web site with specific url

Tags: asp.net-core, dotnet-cli

How can I specify using dotnet cli to run my web app using specific configurations.
I know hosting.json can be used but I did not find any documentation how to do this and how this relates to the dotnet cli.

Comment: Can you clarify what configurations you're trying to set?  Are you trying to make it listen on a specific port or ip address?  If so [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289816/how-to-start-a-asp-net-core-1-0-rc2-app-that-doesnt-listen-to-the-localhost/37289990#37289990) might be helpful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at this sample: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/samples/CookieSample/Program.cs#L11

Tweaked for command line:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddCommandLine(args).Build();

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
```

Then call `dotnet run server.urls=http://localhost:5001/`

Comment: Thank you Tratcher. Exactly what I was missing. Works now!.

Comment: The orginal dotnet command is :
dotnet run --urls "http://localhost:5100"
dotnet run --urls "http://localhost:5100;https://localhost:5101"

Answer (score 4):

Try `.UseUrls` on Program.cs with specific port.

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls("http://localhost:5020")
                .Build();

            host.Run();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this and the output suggests that it's serving on the IP yet my phone still says it's not reachable for some reason. Although IIS on the same machine serves just fine!?

Answer (score 0):

try the below command, its sets the environment variable and you will be able to access with the IP:5000.

set ASPNETCORE_SERVER.URLS=http://0.0.0.0:5000/