# Running RC2 project on defined port

Tags: docker, dockerfile, .net-core, asp.net5, .net-core-rc2

Ok, I created empty RC2 project and running locally using VS 2015 it works.

Now I want to deploy it to linux server using docker - so how should my dockerfile look? I have been following [these instructions](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/tree/master/1.0.0-rc2), and this is what I ended up with:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.0.0-preview1

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN dotnet restore

EXPOSE 5004
ENTRYPOINT dotnet run
```

then I built my app to image:
**docker build -t my_app .**

and run using:
**docker run -t -p 8080:5004 my_app**

After that I got information that image is running and it's listening on localhost:5000. Unfortunetly I have been trying to connect to this serwer with xxxx:5000, xxxx:5004 and xxxx:8080 and none of those addresses worked (xxxx being the server address).

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The problem is that your application is listening on `localhost` rather than the internal IP address which Docker is forwarding requests to.  Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289816/how-to-start-a-asp-net-core-1-0-rc2-app-that-doesnt-listen-to-the-localhost/) for configuring your application to run on a host other than `localhost`.

Comment: I have also came across [this tutorial ][1]that shows how to add docker support to project 

[1]: https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2016/05/17/running-and-debugging-an-asp-net-core-rc2-application-running-in-docker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell kestrel which port to listen on by using the `UseUrls()` extension method, like this:

(this generally goes in the `Program.Main()` entry point method for me)

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5004")
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

In this case, you would run the docker image like this:

```
$ docker run -d -p 8080:5004 my_app
```

I chose the `-d` option to run as a daemon. Just make sure that the EXPOSED port in your Dockerfile matches the one specified in `UseUrls`. For a complete example of this, feel free to look at my github sample project: https://github.com/mw007/adventure-works

Answer (score 2):

You can also specify the Urls at Dockerfile level (better if you want to reuse the Container). Here it is the full Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet

RUN printf "deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian jessie main\n" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

EXPOSE 5000/tcp
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run", "--server.urls=http://0.0.0.0:5000"]
```

You also need to modify the Program.cs file to read the configuration from the main args:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ASPNETCORE_")
            .Build();

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
```

You have the step-by-step tutorial and why in this blog post:
https://www.sesispla.net/blog/language/en/2016/05/running-asp-net-core-1-0-rc2-in-docker/